# Asymptotic notation for summations

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

I am having trouble understanding why the following equation is true for asymptotic notation

[image]

Comment: This doesn't make a whole lot of sense; whatever function `f` is, `f(k)` is a constant for each `k`, so `O(f(k))` is `O(1)` and there is no need for the function to exist at all.

Comment: f(k) is not evaluated, it represents any function of k. For example, it could be sum of O(k^2). This equation is taken from CLRS p1146.

Comment: The sum is from `k = 1` to `n`, so `k` is not a free variable in this expression. It looks like an abuse of notation to me.

Comment: You are correct, the runtime is dependent on n, not k. However, if we know the asymptotic runtime for a given value of k, this allows us to calculate the runtime in terms of n (i believe). k does not necessarily have to be a free variable for there to be an overall runtime. In this case, as CLRS itself says, this manipulation is done to apply O notation to the variable n rather than k.

Comment: Yes, but in the left hand side there is nothing dependent on `n` inside the `O(...)` brackets, so it might as well say `O(1)`. That's my point.

Comment: I would illustrate an example here but the abscence of LaTeX makes it very difficult. Page 159 of CLRS has an example of this property being used which should hopefully demonstrate my point.

Comment: You can use LaTeX when asking a question on http://cs.stackexchange.com/ , which is a more appropriate place for this question than Stack Overflow; but you should definitely include all of the extra details and context that you are adding in these comments, and anything else you think someone might need to know to explain this equation to you. That said, regardless of what is on pages 1146 or 159 of CLRS, this equation doesn't make much sense, and if taken literally it is false.

Answer (score 0):

This formula made me think a little bit. The problem with this is not that it is, that there is a lot of abuse of notation when it comes to asymptotic notation and there are a lot of definitions that come out as equal but make it harder to write down proofs.

However, I will try an interpretation of this formula and then we'll see if we get some sense into it.

To begin with, I normally interpret `O(f(n))` as the set of functions for which `f(n)` is an asymptotic upper bound. This is why I prefer to write `g \in O(f)` instead of `g = O(f)` but as the latter is quite common I interpret them equally.

The right side of the equation is just a function written as a sum of some functions. nothing special here.

On the left side it get interesting. A sum over some big-Os. Here it is not imidietly clear what a sum of sets, as I interpret big-O, should be, but if your read it out, it makes sense:

> The sum of upper bounds of some functions is an upper bound of the sum of the functions.

And this is what you do in the analysis of algorithms all the time. If you have a functions that runs two subfunction, `f` in `O(n)` and `g` in `O(m)`, then both together run in `O(n+m)`

This is now a special case, since the sum of the functions uses always the same function with arguments ranging from 1 to n. But this barely changes anything. Sure, you could view some of them as constants, but the left side is by no means independent of `n` as @kaya3. There is at least the last term `O(f(n))` for `k = n` which depends clearly on `n` and then there are `n` terms in the sum. So even if you sum up `n` times a constant upper bound, this should not result in a constant upper bound.

To close this: To me this looks like a definition: if you see the left hand side think of it as the right hand side and you get a result you are looking for.